# MSBuild conditional reference in ProjectC based on whether running ProjectA or ProjectB

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, xamarin-studio

I have three projects in my solution:

```
ProjectA : contains reference to ProjectC
ProjectB : contains reference to ProjectC
ProjectC : references third.party.dll.A or third.party.dll.B
```

During compilation, I want Project C to reference either **third.party.dll.A** or **third.party.dll.B** depending on which one of ProjectA or ProjectB that I a have set as the startup project and am launching/compiling via the IDE.

How can I set up my solution so I can use an MSBuild conditional reference in ProjectC.csproj to determine whether ProjectA or ProjectB is currently being compiled?

(In the .csproj file I tried checking if $(DefineConstants) contains a certain value, but it seems like $(DefineConstants) only contains the symbols defined in ProjectC, and not those defined in ProjectA and ProjectB.)

(FYI: I am using Xamarin Studio on a Mac. But I assume that if there is a way to make this work for Visual Studio, it should also work in Xamarin Studio.)

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do that. Project references in MSBuild are not configurable to the extend you want them to be, configuration of the build for referenced projects are hard-coded in standard msbuild .targets files.

There are couple of possible workarounds for your case. The easiest one is to create two projects: `ProjectC1` and `ProjectC2`. C1 will use one of the third-party library, while C2 will use another one. You can make `ProjectC1` and `ProjectC2` share the same source files, so there will be no code duplication.

Another possible workaround is to make references to `third.party.dll.A` and `third.party.dll.B` with conditional assignment, like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Condition="'$(BuildA)' == 'true'" Include="pathto\third.party.dll.A">
    <Name>third.party.dll.A</Name>
  </ProjectReference>
  <ProjectReference Condition="'$(BuildB)' == 'true'" Include="pathto\third.party.dll.B">
    <Name>third.party.dll.B</Name>
  </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

If you do this, you should also set similar conditions for the build output directories, based on values of properties BuildA and BuildB you should configure $(IntDir) and $(OutDir) to separate locations, because your incremental build will be seriously broken otherwise.

Then you can build from command line passing additional parameters:

```
> msbuild ProjectA.csproj /p:BuildA=true
```

or

```
> msbuild ProjectB.csproj /p:BuildB=true
```

To make the build work like this in Visual Studio, or Xamarin Studio, you have to set environment variable before launching the VS or XS. Note that you cannot switch from one configuration to another without re-launching VS or XS.

Comment: I'm liking the idea of a ProjectC1 and ProjectC2 best because I am compiling via Xamarin Studio instead of the command line. However, do you happen know if there there a way to make C1 and C2 "share" the same source files while keeping the source files in Xamarin with a "Portable Library" instead of a "Shared Project".  (The reason I need my code in a Portable Library is I run into a different issue when using a Shared Project.)

Comment: @AnthonyTietjen, you should be able to share the sources between projects easily. It was a while ago when I did it with .csproj, but I am doing it all the time with .vcxproj. With C# the easiest way is to place both .csproj files in the same directory, so that VS or Xamarin wouldn't want to make copies of the files in two different locations. For C++ projects you can achieve the same by editing .vcxproj file and tweaking `<ClCompile>` items to use a location you want them to be.

Comment: @AnthonyTietjen -- one more thing about sharing sources between two projects. You probably will need to assign different $(IntDir) values for these two projects, so they don't confuse their intermediate results. The $(OutDir) could be the same, I will assume you will want the output to be named differently. If you wan the DLL to be the same name, then assign $(OutDir) to point to different locations as well.